# How to get headings and paragraphs siblings simultaneously with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have this kind of **HTML DOM structure**:

```html
<div>
  <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
  <p>First paragraph</p>
  <p>Second Paragraph</p>

  <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
  <p>Second Paragraph</p>
  <p>Second Paragraph</p>
  <p>Second Paragraph</p>

  <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <blockquote>...</blockquote>
</div>
```

Sometimes I have one `<h3>` and three pragraphs, others one `<h3>`, three paragraphs and a blockquote, but **always one heading with some siblings**.

I would like to create **an object** that englobes this structure inside a **json** like this **(I'm using Puppeteer)**:

```json
[
  {
    "h3": "heading textContent",
    "p":  "paragraph textContent",
    "p":  "paragraph textContent",
  },
  {
    "h3": "heading textContent",
    "p":  "paragraph textContent",
    "blockquote":  "blockquote textContent",
  },
  {
    "h3": "heading textContent",
    "p":  "...",
    "p":  "...",
  },
]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share your attempt. Seems pretty straightforward to select that div, then iterate the children and chunk them into pieces based on their tags: if it's an h3, start a new object, otherwise add a key for that tag name. Also, your object format is invalid so the specification here in unclear. You can't have two of the same `"p"` keys on an object--they must be unique.

Comment: I don't know how to do it. At the moment I have created a **JSON** file with all the `<h3>` and on the other hand another object with the `<p>`.

Comment: Sorry, but the site requires a code attempt. There's always some step you can make. Break the problem down: can you select the parent and iterate the children? Then add an `if` in your loop and try to figure out which tag you're looking at. If you can't do that, maybe break the problem down further and figure out how to select things in Puppeteer. You might try Codementor or Upwork if you aren't willing to make an attempt at writing some code or clarify the problem.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it next time. I'll try it and I will edit the answer with my attempt. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Why not do it this time :). You can [edit] the question to be on-topic and clarify your intent. If you do arrive at an answer, please clarify the question to help future visitors, then post a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) rather than editing your answer into the question. Thanks and good luck.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is not as difficult as I thought and it is **using CSS selectors** not Puppeter. With this HTML structure:

```html
<div class="class1 class2">
  <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
  <p>First paragraph</p>
  <p>Second Paragraph</p>
  <blockquote>...</blockquote>
</div>
```

You need to use the following code to get **all h3, p and blockquotes** of the *div* element with `class="class1 class2"`. The key is the line `'.class1.class2 h3, p, blockquote'`.

```js
const resultData = [];

const data = [...document.querySelectorAll('.class1.class2 h3, p, blockquote')].map((el) => {
  if (el.nodeName === 'H3') return { h3: el.textContent.trim() };
  if (el.nodeName === 'P') return { p: el.textContent.trim() };
  if (el.nodeName === 'BLOCKQUOTE') return { blockquote: el.textContent.trim() };
});

resultData.push(data);
```

At the end, you will get the **following JSON file**:

```json
[
  {
    "content": [
      {
        "h3": "h3 textcontent"
      },
      {
        "p": "p textcontent"
      },
      {
        "p": "p textcontent"
      },
    ]
  }
]
```